# Can't set "page layout" for category in Magento 1.7.0.2 programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I want to create categories in Magento within a PHP script. Everything is working fine, but not setting the page layout for the category:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

// <MyProblem>
$category->setData('page_layout', 'two_columns_left');
// </MyProblem>

$category->setStoreId($storeViewId);
$category->setName($name);
$category->setIsActive('1');
$category->setIncludeInMenu('1');
$category->setDescription($description);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setPageLayout('two_columns_left');
$category->setIsAnchor('0');
$category->setParentId($parentId);
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$category->save();
```

Comment: have you try my solution? it work for me so I'm damm sure it will work for you

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. It has already worked. I have not choosen the correct storeview in the backend to see the result :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set category layout from this way

```
 $category->setPageLayout('three_columns');
```

Where  `three_columns`  is your custom layout you can set your different layout among

```
- empty
 - one_column
 - two_columns_left
 - two_columns_right
 - three_columns
```